# How do I restore my event handler bindings in jQuery after a partial postback in salesforce?

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I have a data table on a visualforce page, the contents of which change based on a value selected in a controlling dropdown list.  The data table contains input fields that need to be either enabled or disabled client-side.  I'm using jQuery for this and it all works find until the postback following a changed to the value in the controlling  dropdown list.  The data table is repopulated correctly, but because the document.ready event doesn't fire after the partial postback, I lose all the event bindings I set up during the page's initial load.

How do I hook them up again, is there another event I can use?

Many thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using event delegation, the `$(container).on('event', 'selector', function() {...})` version of `on()`. See [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), especially the section about delegated events.

Answer (score 1):

So after a bit of trawling around some salesforce documentation, I found a useful attribute to the apex:actionFunction mark-up, namely 'oncomplete'.  It lets you specify some javascript to be executed after the postback has finished.  Very useful.